# How to use session for different users from different classes?

Tags: php, authentication, session, permissions

I'm able to successfully create sessions and run them and it works fine in pages exclusive to those particular users.

For example, if there are 8 pages for admin then those 8 pages will contain the code which checks only for the admin session from the admin class.

But if there is a page where all three have the user permission to, which will be the login page I'm unable to handle three sessions together for three separate users. When I am already logged in to the system using any one of the users and then try to go to the login page it should automatically redirect me to that user's exclusive home page. But instead it asks me to enter the login credentials again.

My PHP code:

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_SESSION['p_login'])){
            header("location:login_tests/Patient.php");
        
    }
    else if(isset($_SESSION['d_login'])){
        
            header("location:login_tests/Doctor.php");
        
    }
    else if(isset($_SESSION['a_login'])){
            header("location:admin/Dashboard.php");
    }    

    // Login functionalities
    if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){

        // Patient login
        if($_POST['users']=="patient"){
            session_start();
            include_once 'classes/patient.php';
            $patient = new Patient();
            if ($patient->p_session())
            {
                header("location:login_tests/Patient.php");
            }

            $patient = new Patient();
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
                $login = $patient->p_login($_REQUEST['username'],$_REQUEST['password']);
                if($login){
                    header("location:login_tests/Patient.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('Login Failed!');</script>";
                }
            }
        }
        // Doctor login
        else if($_POST['users']=="doctor"){
            session_start();
            include_once 'classes/doctor.php';
            $doctor = new Doctor();
            if ($doctor->d_session())
            {
                header("location:login_tests/Doctor.php");
            }

            $doctor = new Doctor();
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
                $login = $doctor->d_login($_REQUEST['username'],$_REQUEST['password']);
                if($login){
                    header("location:login_tests/Doctor.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('Login Failed!');</script>";
                }
            }
        }
        // Admin login
        else{
            session_start();
            include_once 'classes/admin.php';
            $admin = new Admin();
            if ($admin->a_session())
            {
                header("location:admin/Dashboard.php");
            }

            $admin = new Admin();
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
                $login = $admin->a_login($_REQUEST['username'],$_REQUEST['password']);
                if($login){
                    header("location:admin/Dashboard.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('Login Failed!');</script>";
                }
            }
        }
        
    } 
    // Registration functionalities
    else if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){

        include_once 'classes/patient.php';
        $patient = new Patient();

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    
            $register = $patient->p_register($_REQUEST['name'],$_REQUEST['gender'], $_REQUEST['dob'],  $_REQUEST['nic'], $_REQUEST['address'],$_REQUEST['email'],  $_REQUEST['username'], $_REQUEST['password']);
            if($register){
                echo "<script>alert('Registration Successful!');</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Entered email address or username already exists!');</script>";
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code sample is too long. Please [edit] your post to pare your code down to a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, your problem is the 3 session variables `$_SESSION['p_login']`, `$_SESSION['d_login']` and `$_SESSION['a_login']`.

There is no need to use 3 separate variables, use 1: `$_SESSION['user'] = value`.

Give it a value according to permission (e.g. patient=1, docter=2, admin=3). Then you only have to test:

```
if( $_SESSION['user'] < 2 ) only permission for patient pages.
if( $_SESSION['user'] < 3 ) permission for patient pages + docter pages.
if( $_SESSION['user'] < 4 ) permission for all pages.
```

Comment: You have said to use only 1 $_SESSION variable, may i know what is the exact value I should assign to that variable?

Comment: Whatever you want, based on what type of user it is. As long as you can logically test it. Inside the _Login functionalities_  you have to set the session variable, so you can read it in other pages.